# Why does WKPanGestureRecognizer end each gesture after 6-7 seconds?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, gesture, watchos

I'm testing `WKPanGestureRecognizer` on my Apple Watch Series 7. It seems the pan gestures are always ended after about 6-7 seconds.

When I lift my finger before that timespan ends, everything behaves as I would expect it: the gesture event fires once with a state of `ended`, and the gesture is finished.

But when I let my finger on the screen, it receives the `ended` state too, always 6 or 7 seconds after the gesture had started. It does not depend on how much I move the finger around.

Is that a bug, or is that configurable or documented somewhere?